# Diff between two branches in a client workspace

Tags: diff, perforce

I have two branches in my local workspace. I need to take a diff between them and capture the filenames in a text file.

I looked into diff and diff2

```
p4 diff
```

gives the diff between a branch in the local client workspace and it's counterpart on the server

```
p4 diff2
```

can only be used to get the diff between two branches which are on the server.

By the way, if I do "Diff Against" on the two branches on the server through p4v client, I am able to see the list of the diff files. But I don't see anything there which would import the filesnames to a text file.

But if I try p4 diff2 through the command line on the two branches on the server, i get  `- protected namespace - access denied.`

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you `p4 sync` both branches to the required version first, then all the files are on your disk and available to the regular `diff` command (not a `p4` sub-command) - see [the man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff).

For example:

```
diff -qr branch1 branch2
```

Might give you output like:

```
Files branch1/newfile and branch2/newfile differ
Only in branch1: newfile2
```

Comment: No sorry. Don't know `C#` or the Perforce .NET API.